# Java JAX WS create a method from java code that produce/accept a XML

Tags: java

Java JAX WS create a method from java code that produce/accept a XML like this

```
<web:listMd5FileSynchronizedSlave>
<descricaoSumaria>Test file sincrona </descricaoSumaria>
        <fileFullPath>
<file>/opt/apagar/file01</file>
                <type>1</type>
</fileFullPath>
        <fileFullPath>
                <file>/opt/apagar/file02</file>
                <type>0</type>
    </fileFullPath> 
        <fileFullPath>…….dynamic number of FileFullPath tag sent from the client 
</web:listMd5FileSynchronizedSlave>
```

On my interface I have a code :

```
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)
@WebMethod (operationName = "listMd5FileSynchronizedSlave") String listMd5FileSynchronizedSlave( 

            @WebParam(name = "descricaoSumaria") String descricao , 
            @WebParam(name = "fileFullPath") String [] fileFullPath 
    ) ;
```

And the implementation is :

```
@Override
    public String listMd5FileSynchronizedSlave(String descricao, String [] fileFullPath) {…}
```

This produce a XML like this

```
<web:listMd5FileSynchronizedSlave>
          <descricaoSumaria>Test file sincrona </descricaoSumaria>
          <fileFullPath>/opt/apagar/file01</fileFullPath>
          <fileFullPath>/opt/apagar/*.sh</fileFullPath>
          <fileFullPath>/opt/apagar/*.properties</fileFullPath>
</web:listMd5FileSynchronizedSlave>
```

How should I change my code to generate and accept a XML with sub tag of  ?

```
<fileFullPath>
            <file>/opt/apagar/file02</file>
            <type>0</type>
</fileFullPath>
```

Tanks for this help